# Powershell Python: Change version used

Tags: python, powershell

I'm using windows xp.

I'm trying to use Python in powershell. On my computer I have both Python 3.3 and 2.7 installed. I'm trying to run 2.7 but whenever I type "python" into powershell it opens 3.3.

How do I select the version of Python to run?

Comment: Do you want to change default python version?

Comment: What about `python2` or `python27`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In powershell, enter the following:

```
$Env:PY_PYTHON = 2
```

Then try using the command "py". It should start up Python 2.7. If you ever want to run Python 3.3 again, "py -3" will do the trick.

Comment: To override this setting for scripts, see [PEP 397](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) regarding shebangs in Windows. With the 3.3 installer, `py.exe` and `pyw.exe` are associated with .py and .pyw files, and they process the shebang line.

Comment: Work perfectly, but instead of running the command py -3. Won't it just be easier if I type in python and not py.

Comment: Probably. I just thought it worth mentioning that "py" can launch any version of python you specify.

Answer (score 1):

Something like Python Select? Windows support is experimental but it might be worth a try.

https://github.com/Activestate/pythonselect

There's also switchpy, although that only supports up to Python 3.2.

apipes.blogspot.com/2010/10/switchpy.html?m=1